# An Historical Spoonerism

Tags: cryptic-clues

There was more reading of Wikipedia than usual in the creation of this clue.

> According to Spooner (possessed by Carmen), composer was in the Hundred Years War (6, 2, 6)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I think this should be [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] rather than [tag:cryptic-clues].

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, Spoonerisms are a common trick in cryptic crosswords. I think cryptic-clues is the right tag for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is

> Battle of Chiset

because

> the [Battle of Chiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Chiset) occurred in 1373 as part of the Hundred Years War. Making a [Spoonerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism) of it leads to *Chattel of Bizet*. Georges Bizet composed the opera Carmen. Also, possibly, a chattel is something owned, hence "possessed by Carmen".

Comment: Any ideas about the numbers (6, 2, 6)???

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thats the enumeration

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir (6, 2, 6) is the number of letters in the words of the answer.

Comment: @nickgard: it's "possessed by Carmen composer" (ignoring some punctuation) but otherwise spot on.